# "VT-x is not available" when I start my Virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine

I have created a virtual machine using the VMWare software and getting an error while starting the Virtual Machine. It says "VT-x is not available:

```
00:00:03.916 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_cluster, used:0)
00:00:03.916 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_packet, used:0)
00:00:03.916 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_pagesize, used:0)
00:00:03.916 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_9k, used:0)
00:00:03.916 NAT: zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_16k, used:0)
00:00:03.930 VMSetError: D:\tinderbox\win-4.0\src\VBox\VMM\VMMR3\VM.cpp(350) VMR3Create; rc=VERR_VMX_NO_VMX
00:00:03.930 VMSetError: Unknown error creating VM
00:00:03.931 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={515e8e8d-f932-4d8e-9f32-79a52aead882} aComponent={Console} aText={VT-x is not available. (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).
00:00:03.931 Unknown error creating VM (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)}, preserve=false
00:00:03.944 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_VMX_NO_VMX, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: I had the same error - i deactivated "IO-APIC" in System Settings of the VM. That works for me.

Comment: Disabling the Windows Hyper-V Feature worked for me

Comment: Hyper-V became active again when I updated to Windows 10 without my knowledge.  Keep an eye out for that.

Comment: I had Hyper-V enabled, all was fine but some GenyMotion VMs wouldn't work (anything higher than Android 5.0). The fix for me was in this video, very simple. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y56boAsdptw

Comment: In my case, I installed "Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android".  That pooched all my VBox VMs.  I uninstalled the Emulator, still no dice.  I saw that Hyper-V was not installed, so I installed it and uninstalled it -- that reset flipped the switch and got my VBox VMs working again.

Comment: On your VM, Go to System -> Motherboard -> Un-check this option Enable I/O APIC, and then save the VM, and start it again.

Comment: Guys, I am having the same issue. Virtualization is enabled and Hyper-V is disabled but nothing works for me. Check the question here https://superuser.com/questions/1255078/vt-x-is-not-available-issue-windows-10

Comment: maybe - bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off   . then reboot.

Comment: I had to disable Hyper-V,  followed by disabling the Virtualization from Bios and Re-enabling the virtualization from Bios did the trick.

Answer (score 137):

You might try reducing your base memory under settings to around 3175MB and reduce your cores to 1. That should work given that your BIOS is set for virtualization. Use the f12 key, security, virtualization to make sure that it is enabled. If it doesn't say VT-x that is ok, it should say VT-d or the like.

Comment: For some reason, I was not able to edit the number of cores in the UI, since it was disabled. Had to edit the "*.vbox" of the corresponding image to change the cores to 1.

Comment: I was having a similar problem and reducing the memory resolved my issue, why does that work?  I am on a virtual machine installing a virtual machine.  Inception.

Comment: Stackoverflow to the rescue :-D

Comment: Where are you entering the F12 key to do this?  In virtual box?

Comment: Why would reducing base memory and cores work?

Comment: This happened to me after installing latest Docker for Windows. It enabled Hyper-V features in Windows 10 and all VirtualBox instances were broken. Disabling Hyper-V solved the issue (see here how: http://www.poweronplatforms.com/enable-disable-hyper-v-windows-10-8/) but now Docker is broken :-/

Comment: Reducing the VM's memory allocation worked for me. It's weird but it works.

Comment: In my case the IT pushed some updates which enabled the Hpery-V, disable it and all your VirtualBox Virtual machines should start working. The link posted by Gabor Nagy would be helpful.

Comment: had similar problem and nothing helped.
But disabling disable Device Guard or Credential Guard solved my issue: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146361?sliceId=1&dialogID=379083667&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&stateId=0+0+379091524

Comment: @GáborNagy that worked for me. Want to add it as an answer?

Comment: @ChrisAnderson This question is marked "closed as off topic" so I could not add it as an answer, just as a comment. I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 8):

VT-x can normally be disabled/enabled in your BIOS.

When your PC is just starting up you should press DEL (or something) to get to the BIOS settings. There you'll find an option to enable VT-technology (or something).

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure your processor supports Intel Virtualization (VT-x) or AMD Virtualization (AMD-V)?

Here you can find Hardware-Assisted Virtualization Detection Tool ( http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ee2a17f-8538-4619-8d1c-05d27e11adb2&displaylang=en) which will tell you if your hardware supports VT-x.

Alternatively you can find your processor here: http://ark.intel.com/Default.aspx. All AMD processors since 2006 supports Virtualization.

Comment: I could not install that Virtualization Detection tool on my windows 2008 R2 64 bit server. Any alternate ways?

Comment: What processor are you using?

Comment: Intel Xeon, E5440 @2.83 GHz 2.91 GHz

Comment: According to: http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=33082&processor=E5440&spec-codes=SLANS,SLBBJ your processor supports VT-x. 
Try this: http://www.itropics.net/index.php/computers/windows/103-vt-x-is-not-available-verrvmxnovmx

Comment: Thanks for your response. which one i should try? There are many options in that link...the problem is that i am trying to install virtual box on my VM machine. I had to raise some ticket to get any settings changed on my VM machine. I will first try to enable Hardware VT and see.

Comment: I was thinking about trying all of them :P

Comment: If you're using a Xeon on a 775 motherboard you probably need to flash microcodes in order to enable VT-x.