# Virtualbox says VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX). What is VT-x?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Samsung Galaxy S6 - 6.0.0 -     API 23 - 1440x2560.

VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

What is this `VT-x` and why is it needed ?

Also I can create a VM and install Linux but why can't I start any Android device on VirtualBox ?

I have genymotion successfully installed but every time I run device it gives me above error.

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: I had the same issue. Disable Hyper-V. It will fix your problem. (Program and features -> Turn windows features on/off -> disable hyper-v)

Answer (score 6):

If you run Windows 8.1/10 Pro, then the problem may be related to a Hyper-V platform from Microsoft. You may try to [uninstall it](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/how-do-i-uninstall-hyper-v/7d268911-47cd-4c52-bfe5-ea41e58067ab?auth=1). Sometimes it's also needed to disable it in a terminal window (using administrator privileges) with `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`.

Answer (score 3):

To sum this up :

> VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

What is VT-x ?

> VT-x is Intel's technology for virtualization on the x86 platform. VT-x allows
>   multiple operating systems to simultaneously share x86 processor
>   resources in a safe and efficient manner.

Possible issues & Solutions :

- VT-X is not enabled in the BIOS settings – VT-X can be disabled from the BIOS settings manually or remotely by some 3rd party applications. Solution is to enter BIOS settings at boot time and re-enable Virtualization (can be VT-x, VT-d, etc.).
- The machine’s CPU doesn’t support VT-X – Although these cases are rare, there are instances where the error is occurring because the PC in question is simply not equipped to support the VT-X technology.
- Hyper-V virtualization is enabled in Windows – This is perhaps the most common cause why this error occurs. Since Microsoft’s Hyper-V technology is known to conflict with VT-X, the OS will automatically disable VT-x if Hyper-V virtualization is enabled. You can disable it via *"Turn Windows features on or off"* menu in Windows settings. Note that one of "Virtual Machine Platform" and/or "Windows Hypervisor Platform" being enabled appear to cause the issue.
- Avast update disabled VT-X – As it turns out, Avast released an update that effectively disables VT-x while the real-time protection is active unless the user enables nested virtualization from the settings menu.
- Core Isolation is enabled – Core isolation is a Windows Defender Security option that is known to conflict with VT-X while it’s enabled. You can disable it from the Windows Defender options menu, or via Settings > Update & Security > Window Security > Device Security > Core Isolation Details > Turn Off

cf. other posts, most from stackexchange
["VT-x is not available" when i start my Virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482223/vt-x-is-not-available-when-i-start-my-virtual-machine)
https://serverfault.com/questions/620273/turn-on-virtualisation-settings-on-windows-2012-r2
https://superuser.com/questions/1266489/virtualbox-states-vt-x-is-not-available-verr-vmx-no-vmx
https://superuser.com/questions/1391838/virtual-box-is-not-working-on-windows-10
https://appuals.com/fix-vt-x-is-not-available-verr_vmx_no_vmx/

Related : [VirtualBox - Kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872842/virtualbox-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detected-an-i686-cpu)

Answer (score 2):

VT-x is Intel's technology for virtualization on the x86 platform. VT-x allows multiple operating systems to simultaneously share x86 processor resources in a safe and efficient manner.

Make sure Virtualization is enabled in your BIOS and that nothing uses it already - Hyper-V is a very common issue.

Please refer [x86 virtualization wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29)

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: i don't have Virtualization option in BIOS .. Is there anything I can do to make genymotion Virtual device work ? and I don't seem to find Hyper-V on " Turn off windows features ON and OFF

Comment: @Saurab Which is your host operating system?

Comment: @Saurab Check whether your processor supports virtualization or not by downloading the Processor Identification Utility http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/processor-utilities-and-programs/intel-processor-identification-utility.html

Comment: @HussainK and if not what we have to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you have enabled the mode Virtualization in the BIOS and if the problem still persists, try going to

> Settings -> Update & Security -> Window security -> Device security -> Core isolation details -> Turn off

and then restart the PC and try again to review the 64-bits VirtualBox environment.

Answer (score 2):

Disable "Virtual Machine Platform" and/or "Windows Hypervisor Platform" from "Turn Windows features on or off" menu in Windows settings. After just restart and open virtual box or VMware. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Windows has a 'Virtualization based Security Guard' which needed to be disabled. I used the powershell tool to get the job done.

`.\DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable -AutoReboot`

Here's a link to the tool:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337

Kudos/source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79583454-bcd1-45a3-bc2e-a6a5078d1dde/why-is-the-hypervisor-running-even-after-i-uninstalled-hyperv?forum=win10itprovirt&prof=required

Answer (score 0):

It took some time and digging to figure out it was issue only with 64-bit VMs that shows above mentioned error, and not the 32-bit VMs.

Although he doesn’t mention the actual error, the root cause of his problem is in Win 10. Hyper-V is greedy and owns the “VT-x” after booting and doesn’t share with Virtual Box at all.

Here is The two solutions:

- Either remove Hyper-V from Windows (if you’re not using it obviously)
  via ‘**Turn Windows features on of off**’
- Edit the BCD to start Windows with the Hyper-V **(hypervisorlaunchtype
  disabled)** as the post illustrates.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that If you have already enabled VTX, and checked that you have vt-d/vt-x enabled in the BIOS, try resetting the VirtualBox settings or re-installing VirtualBox: it might have nothing to do with your PC/Windows configuration.